# Laravel Model orderBy relationship

Tags: laravel

My website has comments. These comments have upvotes.

Comment Model:

```php
public function upvotes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote', 'comment_id')->where('vote', 1);
}
```

```php
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','parent_id');
}
```

Comments can also have child comments.

What I'd like to know is how could I sort these child comments by how many upvotes they have?

Something like...

```php
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','parent_id')->orderBy(upvotes);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with `->where('vote', 1)`?

Comment: Votes are stored as a tinyint in the CommentVote table. 1 is an upvote, 0 is default, and -1 is a downvote. This makes it easy to calculate the total score of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your children function:

```php
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','parent_id');
}
```

Within your controller, fetch the comment childrens:

```php
$childrens = $comment->children()->get();
```

Now, you can use the [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby) collection method to sort your childrens comments by upvote count:

```php
$childrens->sortBy(function($children){
    $children->upvotes->count();
});
```

**Update:** appending to the comment model:

add the `$appends` to the comment model:

Within your commeht model:

```php
protected $appends = ['childrens'];
```

create an accessor to the childrens (also inside comment model):

```php
public function getChildrensAttribute()
{
    $childrens = $this->childrens()->get();
    return $childrens->sortBy(function($children){
        $children->upvotes->count();
    });
}
```

Now, the childrens comments will be appended to the parent comment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm confused. That's exactly what my children function already is

Comment: sorry, i confused with your example function. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This solution will cause n+1 queries, it will query the upvotes for each child comment inside the callback passed to sortBy.

Comment: I'm confused, though. In my controller, I pass a $comments array to the view. 

These comments can have children. Passing sorted children comment directly to the view won't work as they're being called from the Child relationship model. 

Is there any way to put this logic into the Comment model?

Comment: Yes, using the `appends` property. Look at the update on my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer works. However, I needed to add "sortByDesc" for it to work. Also $children->upvotes->count(); didn't work so I switched it to return count($children['upvotes']);

I made an edit to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can query comments ordered by the count of upvotes including the count of child comments.

```
Comment::query()
    ->where('parent_id', $parentId) // or any way to filter by parent
    ->withCount(['upvotes' => function ($query) {$query->where('upvotes.vote', 1);}])
    ->orderBy('upvotes_count')
    ->get()
```